# download class from http://docs.spring.io/

Tags: java, spring, class

I need to download this java class:

```
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.8/api/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.html
```

But i can't find where to download, i really clicked everywhere upon that website. can someone help me to find this code?

It's accepted any other website or link with code of this class.

Comment: It appears to be part of the spring framework. Download that?

Comment: is not possible download only this file? or find only this class code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is from the Spring framework, so you will download the spring library, try to download the following spring library then add it to your project, than just do: 
`import org.springframework.jdbc.object`

[Spring framework accessible from here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/ktcl9wmcum5n0sd/springjars.zip)

and direct link to the jar file of this class is accessible from this link:
[org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE-A](http://www.mediafire.com/download/qilvowxxhd09x85/org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar)

I hope it will help you, best regards

Answer (score 1):

The file can be found [here](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-maintenance/tags/initial/src/org/springframework/jdbc/object/StoredProcedure.java), for example. Google is your friend. Took me less than 3 seconds to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Below link you can use

All Release

http://maven.springframework.org/release/org/springframework/spring/